# Mongoose not updating a model after change

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I tried to update a model for an app I'm making. It's a user model and it used to have a MAC Address which was unique for every user. I removed the MAC and instead added a UUID. Now when I try to create a user (and any one user already exists) I always get this error:

```
{
    "macAddress": "The macAddress \"null\" is already taken."
}
```

This error is formatted by a util function I made based on a mongoose error. So this means mongoose thinks I still have a macAddress property. Earlier I was also getting this error but I still had a MAC back then and I just ignored it. Now I can't ignore it since if I try to save the user it just says that a .save() function doesn't exist. I'm asking how to update my models in mongoose to fit the new Schema - with a UUID instead of MAC. I wiped all my DB data and it didn't work. Here's my User model:

```js
const { Schema, model, models } = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        uuid: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, "UUID is required."],
            match: [
                // 12 characters long, 4 groups of 3 characters separated by hyphens
                /^[0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{3}$/i,
                '"{VALUE}" is not a valid UUID.',
            ],
        },
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, "Username is required."],
            unique: [true, 'The username "{VALUE}" is already taken.'],
            trim: true,
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, "Email is required"],
            unique: [true, 'The email "{VALUE}" is already taken.'],
            match: [
                /^[A-Za-z0-9_\.]+@[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}$/,
                '"{VALUE}" is not a valid email.',
            ],
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, "Password is required."],
        },
        _tags: {
            type: [
                {
                    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: "Tag",
                },
            ],
            default: [],
        },
        _token: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true, versionKey: false }
);

// before it was `const userModel = models["User"] || model("User", userSchema);`
const userModel = model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = userModel;
```

This is my register route:

```js
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { uuid, username, email, password } = req.body;

        if (!(uuid && username && email && password)) {
            return res
                .status(400)
                .json({ message: "Please fullfil all fields." });
        }

        // Make Sure The UUID Is Unique
        let userWithSameUUID = (await getUsers({ uuid })).users[0];

        if (userWithSameUUID)
            return res.status(409).json({
                message: "This UUID is already registered.",
            });

        let encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

        let user = await createUser({
            uuid,
            username,
            email: email.toLowerCase(),
            password: encryptedPassword,
        });

        // Check For Validation Errors
        if (user.err) {
            let { err } = user;
            let duplicateErrCodes = [11000, 11001];

            if (duplicateErrCodes.includes(err.code)) {
                return res.status(409).json(formatDuplicateError(err));
            }

            return res.status(400).json(formatValidationError(err));
        }

        user._token = jwt.sign(
            {
                _id: user._id,
                username: user.username,
                uuid: user.uuid,
            },
            process.env.TOKEN_KEY
        );

        await user.save();

        res.status(201).json({
            user: { ...user.toJSON(), password: undefined },
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
});
```

createUser function:

```js
async function createUser(user) {
    try {
        const newUser = await new User(user).save();

        return newUser;
    } catch (err) {
        return { err };
    }
}
```

Comment: You wiped all DB and it is still giving "The macAddress \"null\" is already taken."? Double check if the db you wiped is the DB that your application uses.

Comment: @SuleymanSah I am sure I wiped the DB.

Comment: What does "wiped all my DB" mean?

Comment: @Joe It means that my whole database was wiped and there's no data inside it.

Comment: Deleting the data doesn't remove json schemas, indexes, or collection metadata.  Try dropping the database entirely and let mongoose recreate everything with the new schema.

Comment: @Joe Hi, dropping the DB worked. Submit this as an answer so I can mark it as best.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code in my system and it worked properly, And as you mentioned in your query, you need to remove old data from the database which contains the MAC address because, in your previous schema, you mentioned MAC address is required and unique so you need to remove that from unique indexes also.

This issue happens when we kept any key unique and replace it with another key.

Comment: I don't understand what you want me to do. Could you elaborate?

Comment: As you mentioned, You used MAC address first then change it to uuid and still you are facing the same issue so check in Mongodb indexes. Is the MAC address already there?? If yes, then remove it.

Comment: I have already wiped the db so there's no mac address nor is there a mac in the model. the problem i believe is that mongoose thinks it still exists.

Comment: I don't think that should happen. but still you can use `.lean()`  after your query. 
Ex. `collectionName.findOne().lean()`

Comment: What is `.lean()` supposed to do? I don't really know. How exactly will that help?

Comment: `.lean()` returns the document as POJO (plain old JavaScript objects) so if you are doing any javascript operations/populating something it returns with overall data(with populated object and output of javascript operations). You can refer [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html).